# What is the difference between RHEl packages : httpd24-httpd.x86_64 and httpd.x86_64?

Tags: linux, apache, package, rhel

yum search apache gives me: httpd.x86_64 and httpd24-httpd.x86_64

```
    $ yum search apache |grep httpd
    *Note* Spacewalk repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access Spacewalk repositories.
    httpd.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
    httpd24-httpd.x86_64 : Apache HTTP Server
```

What is the difference between these two packages? Which one should be chosen?
Thanks!

This is not an error encountered. I want to know which package should be installed

Comment: httpd is provided with RHEL server package and httpd24 is the RHSCL package. RHSCL httpd contais latest httpd version.